# Who is responsible for C# memory allocation?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

What part of the .NET framework takes responsibility to allocate memory. Is it GC?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the runtime...

Comment: CLR allocates and GC deallocates! That Deallocated memory is used by CLR for next allocation. So cycle continues so I would say both are responsible..... :)

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Well, not quite. The GC isn't just a thing on top of the heap freeing stuff, it literally *is* the heap so you can't really say it's not involved in the allocation, it's actually very much involved in the allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the CLR but in close cooperation with the GC. And the GC is a part of the CLR so it's not such a clear division.

Allocation takes place at the start of the free section of the Heap, it is a very simple and fast operation. Allocation on the Large Object Heap (LOH) is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Do Visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38069/Memory-Management-in-NET

**Allocation of Memory**

> "Generally .NET is hosted using Host process, during debugging .NET
>   creates a process using VSHost.exe which gives the programmer the
>   basic debugging facilities of the IDE and also direct managed memory
>   management of the CLR. After deploying your application, the CLR
>   creates the process in the name of its executable and allocates memory
>   directly through Managed Heaps.
>
> When CLR is loaded, generally two managed heaps are allocated; one is
>   for small objects and other for Large Objects. We generally call it as
>   SOH (Small Object Heap) and LOH (Large Object Heap). Now when any
>   process requests for memory, it transfers the request to CLR, it then
>   assigns memory from these Managed Heaps based on their size.
>   Generally, SOH is assigned for the memory request when size of the
>   memory is less than 83 KBs( 85,000 bytes). If it is greater than this,
>   it allocates memory from LOH. On more and more requests of memory .NET
>   commits memory in smaller chunks."

Upon reading further this paragraphs, Its the CLR with the help of Windows (32bit or 64Bit) it "allocates" the memory.

The **"De-allocation"** is managed by GC.

> "The relationships between the Object and the process associated with
>   that object are maintained through a Graph. When garbage collection is
>   triggered it deems every object in the graph as garbage and traverses
>   recursively to all the associated paths of the graph associated with
>   the object looking for reachable objects. Every time the Garbage
>   collector reaches an object, it marks the object as reachable. Now
>   after finishing this task, garbage collector knows which objects are
>   reachable and which aren’t. The unreachable objects are treated as
>   Garbage to the garbage collector."

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, many kinds of modern "garbage collectors" don't actually collect garbage as their primary operation.  Instead, they often identify everything in an area of memory that isn't garbage and move it somewhere that is known not to contain anything of value.  Unless the area contained an object that was "pinned" and couldn't be moved (in which case things are more complicated) the system will then know that the area of memory from which things were moved contains nothing of value.

In many such collectors, once the last reference to an object has disappeared, no bytes of memory that had been associated with that object will ever again be examined prior to the time that they get blindly overwritten with new data.  If the GC expects that the next use of the old region of memory will be used to hold new objects, it will likely zero out all the bytes in one go, rather than doing so piecemeal to satisfy allocations, but if the GC expects that it will be used as a destination for objects copied from elsewhere it may not bother.  While objects are guaranteed to remain in memory as long as any reference exists, once the last reference to an object has ceased to exist there may be no way of knowing whether every byte of memory that had been allocated to that object has actually been overwritten.

While .NET does sometimes have to take affirmative action when certain objects (e.g. those whose type overrides `Finalize`) are found to have been abandoned, in general I think it's best to think of the "GC" as being not a subsystem that "collects" garbage, but rather as a garbage-collected memory pool's *manager*, that needs to *at all times* be kept informed of everything that isn't garbage.  While the manager's duties include the performance of GC cycles, they go far beyond that, and I don't think it's useful to separate GC cycles from the other duties.